# Custompage Module-Issue with CSS (Drupal-6.x)

Tags: css, drupal

I'm new to Drupal and have recently installed the custompage module. I received a lot of errors until I placed  "custom.tpl.php" in the custompage module folder. I am able to navigate to the custom page from the primary links. But, the CSS I created for that specific page is not showing up. I'm thinking it's because "custom.tpl.php" is located in the module folder of Drupal Core and my CSS is in the theme folder. But I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

I tried to copy the "custom.tpl.php" in my themes folder, but then I receive a lot of errors.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the module. The css should be available to every page in your theme.
Make sure that your CSS file is mentioned in YOURTEMPLATE.info file (YOURTEMPLATE is the name of your template).

It should look like that:

```
stylesheets[all][]   = YOURCSS.css
```

If your css file is in YOURTEMPLATE.info, try to clear drupal cache, go to admin/settings/performance and clear cache.